# Sorting of different types in C# List

Tags: c#, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
```

It contains at least two class instance. I want to sort it by one field, which contains in both of them. Please help me to write IComparer for Array.Sort() method or give me please an advice to make another structure for this task (a list with two class instance).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend that you add a parent interface for those two if you need them together. Then using `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList` you can just use linq's `.OrderBy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  public sealed class MyComparer: System.Collections.IComparer {
    // We want just one Comparer instance
    public static MyComparer Comparer {
      get;
    } = new MyComparer();

    private MyComparer() {
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        return 0;
      else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null))
        return -1;
      else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        return 1;

      // Providing that the fields of interest are of type int 
      int leftField = (x is FirstType) 
        ? ((FirstType) x).FieldOfInterest1 
        : ((SecondType) x).FieldOfInterest2;

      int rightField = (y is FirstType) 
        ? ((FirstType) y).FieldOfInterest1 
        : ((SecondType) y).FieldOfInterest2;

      return leftField.CompareTo(rightField);   
    }
  }

  ...

  ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

  ...

  myList.Sort(MyComparer.Comparer);
```

But remember, `ArrayList` is an *obsolete* class, try changing your design at least into `List<Object>` or (a better choice) `List<SomeBaseClassOrInterface>`.

Comment: myList.Sort(MyComparer.Comparer.Compare);

Comment: Thank you so much!